# Cluster quality measures

Tags: clustering, matlab

Does Matlab provide any facility for evaluating clustering methods? (cluster compactness and cluster separation. ....) 
Or is there any toolbox for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [CVAP](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14620), there are a lot of validation incdices

Answer (score 2):

The [Statistics](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/toolbox/stats/bq_w_hm.html#brjvcre-1) toolbox provides [silhouette plot](http://bit.ly/JBBJX5) which allows to gauge clusters *tightness* and *separation*. (There is also a function to compute cophenetic correlation (to assess how well distance information is reproduced in hierarchical clustering), but it won't answer your question.)

It seems there is a dedicated [Clustering Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7486) on Matlab Central, but I have no experience with it.
I believe other utilities related to [cluster validity](http://machaon.karanagai.com/validation_algorithms.html) are within easy reach with Google.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should also mention that I want use validation function as fitness/goal function for particle swarm clustering.

Answer (score 2):

Not in Matlab, but [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) (Java) provides a dozen or so cluster quality measures for evaluation.